# Difference between tty and ttyS and pts and vcsa?

Tags: linux, terminal, tty

I can't understand what is difference among tty, ttyS, pts and vcsa?
Are they same?
when we connect a serial cable to a server which hosts unix-like operating system, which ones of these type of terminals( If i call them correctly)  will be activate ? 
Also, which one of these are related with my keyboard ?

Comment: Did you look at the q/a's offered you as *related* when you asked this question? Look over to the right - there's a column there headed *Related* which has made some machine matches on the subject for you. They all answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

tty - a native terminal, either kernel-emulated or hardware-implemented.

ttys - serial console

pty - Pseudo-terminal service, something emulated by a software like screen or ssh.

vcs, vcsa - virtual console memory. [Explanation here.](http://linux.die.net/man/4/vcsa)

---

Keyboard is usually with tty and/or pty, while a serial cable goes with ttyS

Comment: These aren't necessarily the names for *all* consoles since, in theory, device nodes can have any name just like any other file. For instance, a driver might name a console "coolCompanyTty0"

Comment: `/dev/tty` are used by the kernel to interface with built in devices such as monitor, keyboard or console terminal. whilst `/dev/ttys` are files for terminals (devices) connected through the serial. <https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-dev-ttyS-and-dev-tty-device-files>